# Visual Studio Team System 2008 & Domain Issues

Tags: tfs

We have TFS installed in a US server. We need to login into VPN to access the TFS server. TFS is configured to use with company's domain user account. However my system is part of the domain. Hence I couldn't access the TFS. I have Visual Studio Team System Developer edition. Can someone here help how to access TFS server installed with different domain?

Regards,

Krish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS uses the domain information of the current logged in Windows account, it's part of the TFS API.

If you're logging into the machine with an account which is on a different domain (*Note*: Local users are also on a different domain) you will not get single-sign-on.

As far as I'm aware there isn't a way around the authentication model which VSTS uses. You *could* write your own VSTS-style extensions using the existing VS API which say, uses a config file for the authentication credentials as the TFS API does support authentication through a manually-created user (we have an external application at work which authenticates against our TFS server and is used by employees of our many offices on different domains).

Answer (score 1):

For codeplex you have to connect to TFS using 'SND\username_cp', maybe you can use 'DOMAINNAME\username' as well.